# C - sorting to list and memory leak

Tags: c, list, sorting, memory, struct

Hi I was deleting memory leaks in my code but I stucked in on moment.

Here I've got functions:

---

```
char* MakeLowerCase(char* word)
{
  char* lower = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word)+1);
  strcpy(lower, word);
  int i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < strlen(lower); i++){
    lower[i] = tolower(lower[i]);
  }
  return lower;
}

void sortedInsert(Word** pH, Word* new_node)
{
    Word* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*pH == NULL || strcmp(MakeLowerCase((*pH)->word), MakeLowerCase(new_node->word)) == 1)
    {
        new_node->pNext = *pH;
        *pH = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *pH;
        while (current->pNext!=NULL &&
               strcmp(MakeLowerCase(current->pNext->word), MakeLowerCase(new_node->word)) == -1)
        {
            current = current->pNext;
        }
        new_node->pNext = current->pNext;
        current->pNext = new_node;
    }
}
```

---

After using these functions my whole list was sorted. But to avoid memory leaks from MakeLowerCase I tried to so something like this:

---

```
void sortedInsert(Word** pH, Word* new_node)
{
    Word* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if(*pH = NULL)
    {
      *pH = new_node;
      return ;
    }

    char* word1 = MakeLowerCase((*pH)->word);
    char* word2 = MakeLowerCase(new_node->word);
    if (*pH == NULL || strcmp(word1, word2) == 1)
    {
        new_node->pNext = *pH;
        *pH = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *pH;
        char* word3 = MakeLowerCase(current->pNext->word);
        char* word4 = MakeLowerCase(new_node->word);
        while (current->pNext!=NULL && strcmp(word3, word4) == -1)
        {
            current = current->pNext;
        }
        new_node->pNext = current->pNext;
        current->pNext = new_node;
    }
    free(word1);
    free(word2);
}
```

---

After changes my list isn't sorted as earlier (just a part of it is sorted in weird way). What did I wrong?

Comment: Ofc after current->pNext I am using free() for word3 and word4

Comment: Just use stricmp()  for comparison.

Comment: I can't use just strcmp() because i need to compare words in small letters.

Comment: Iam afraid you over read the small letter i: str - i - cmp i=ignorecase

Comment: Huh, yes. You're right. I will check that solution

Comment: see `strcasecmp()`;  for `MakeLowerCase()` can you modify bytes within the original string instead of alloc + copy?

Comment: @Milag no, I can't because of this I have to put original string into list.

Comment: @user5329483 huh it really worked. Thank you so much. Is any chance to my program work faster?

Comment: preparing answer...

Comment: waiting for answer...

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, the original approach leaks memory. The returned memory from `MakeLowerCase()` was never freed. In your second attempt you tried to fix this but leaked now word3 and word4. You fixed that later.

The main error is that in your revised function you have a loop advancing `current` while comparing `word3` against the new item. You missed to update `word3` **inside** the loop after advancing `current`. And You have to free it too.

As mentioned in my comment you should simply use str**i**cmp(), the ignore-case brother of `strcmp`, so you don't need `MakeLowerCase()` with all the leaks.

Here my short code. With linked lists I love to use double indirection like `Word**` because it reduces the number of edge cases and by thus the number of conditional instructions.

```
void sortedInsert(Word** pHead, Word* new_node)
{
   //*pHead is a possible insertion point for new_node, like *pHead=new_node
   while (*pHead)
   {
      if (stricmp(new_node->word, (*pHead)->word) < 0)
         break; //Insertion point found.
      pHead = &(*pHead)->pNext;
   }
   //*pHead is the insertion point for new_node, the remaining list at *pHead goes behind us
   new_node->pNext = *pHead;
   *pHead = new_node;
}
```